# How Do I Use The ExtractGrok Processor To Convert JSON To Key/Value?

Tags: apache-nifi, grok

I have syslogs lines like:

```
<333>1 2020-10-09T09:03:00 Myv2 Myv2 - - - {"_id": "authentication", "a_device": {"hostname": null, "ip": "10.10.10.10", "location": {"city": "Lviv", "country": "Ukraine", "state": "Lviv"}}, "alias": "example@email.com", "application": {"key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "name": "Name"}, "auth_device": {"ip": "10.10.10.10", "location": {"city": "Lviv", "country": "Ukraine", "state": "Lviv"}, "name": "+380 00 000 000"}
```

I need convert the JSON part from `logs` to `attributes`, so will be "key": "value" format like:

```
"_id": "authentication",
"a_device_ip": "10.10.10.10",
"location_city": "Lviv"
e t c
```

I am using below flow with ExtractGrok module:[image: flow] and options for ExtractGrok:

[image]

but with 'flowfile-content' option ExtractGrok adding extra string pattern name 'GREEDYDATA' in my json and escape characters like:

[image]

and after EvaluateJsonPath module getting incorrect JSON and returning empty results:

[image]

[image]

If I select 'flowfile-attribute' in ExtractGrok then it is working fine without extra stuff but I don't see how to send that attribute value to EvaluateJsonPath module it is working with only with flow content but not attribute value

Please help with issue or suggest alternative flow:

Answer (score 1):

After your **ExtractGrok** processor, you could add an **AttributesToJSON** processor, which creates already a result JSON containing your GROK-parsed fields inside.